# Flash Builder: how to get flex project framework into ActionScript project?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

If I create a new flex project with flashbuilder, these are the libraries that get included by default through the Flex SDK:

```
http://neo.cycovery.com/flex_problem4.gif
```

If I create a ActionScript project, then the Flex SDK framework with the exact same path includes much less swc files:

```
http://neo.cycovery.com/flex_problem5.gif
```

how do I get the full flex framework into an ActionScript project?

If I try to add for example aircore.swc manually, i get a

```
Description Resource Path Location Type
An internal build error has occurred. Right-click for more information. mvp     Unknown Flex Problem
```

error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erm, you can't.  Flex is a framework that brings more functionality to the table, which Actionscript cannot comprehend (and if I remember correctly, you AS project will be sprite based while Flex's is UIComponent based).  You can only load a Flex application in Actionscript using the Loader.

Can I ask why are you creating an Actionscript project if you want the capabilities of Flex?  Why not just create a Flex project?

Comment: I received a complete ActionScript project which i'm supposed to extend. it relies on libraries like aircore.swc (which is added in a flexproject, but not in an ActionScript project, thus the original question) and others and currently all I try is achieve is to get all the used libraries into the project in order to compile it

Comment: How do you know it needs aircore?  Is this an Air application?  What classes are missing that you need to do this?  You might want to talk to the person that was coding it before you...

Comment: I know it nees aircore because it imports air.net.URLMonitor at one place which is part of aircore.swc (it also imports many files from different other libraries at different places). There's unfortunately no way to get in contact with the author of the software anymore. The softwaredesign looks clean and the compiled executable works very well - but only the actual sourcecode is available, no projectfiles

Comment: Interesting.  He might of jerry-rigged the class from the Air SDK into his Actionscript project.  It shouldn't be used.  My recommendation is removing that part from the code.

Answer (score 0):

In Flash Builder's new Project wizard, you need to create a new "Flex Project" and then select "Desktop" as the application type. In next screen, it asks for default main class, just specify your main .as (ActionScript) class file here.